# Serialization Exception while using LINQ to populate objects (ASP.NET MVC2)

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2, serialization

I have a set of Objects (ViewModel objects used to build strongly typed Views) which I populate from:

1. External J2EE services for dynamic content. I use LINQ2XML to read the XML response returned by J2EE service to populate my objects
2. Local DB for static content. I basically merge the static content from local DB with the dynamic content returned by J2EE services. I use NHibernate and LINQ for this operation.

Once I populate my ViewModels with all the data required, I plan to store them in SESSION (using AppFabric for Out-Of-Proc Session State). I have `[Serializable]`
 attribute for all my ViewModel classes as its required if I plan to store them in out-of-proc Session. However I am getting following exception:

```
Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode. 


Stack Trace: 

[SerializationException: Type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[[TrvCity.Services.ViewModels.ResortsView, TrvCity.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +9452985
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +247
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +160
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +218
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo) +388
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +444
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +133
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1708
```

I have throughly verified all my classes and they are marked as `[Serializable]`. To debug further, I manually (WITHOUT using step 1 & 2 mentioned above) populated them using MOCK DATA and I am able to put them in session, I don't get SerializationException in this case. I feel becuase I am using LINQ (LINQ2XML and LINQ2Objects) to populate them its not liking it.

I would appreciate someone can give me some direction in resolving this.

Here is the code snippet of my objects/classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResortsView : SupplierView
{
    public IList<ProductView> ResortProducts { get; set; }
    public string CheckInTime { get; set; }
    public string CheckOutTime { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ImageView> Images { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SupplierView
{
    public string SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; } 
    public string URL { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ProductView
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public ErrorView PricingError { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because of lazy loading. Try eagerly fetching the collection before attempting to store it in session:

```
IEnumerable<ResortsView> resortsViews = ...
Session["resortsViews"] = resortsViews.ToArray();
```